# How is wave equation equivalent to the Turing reaction-diffusion equation with 3 species?

Tags: waves, complex-systems

I was reading the paper, "[Critical waves and the length problem of biology](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.04430v1.pdf)" by Robert B. Laughlin. He mentions a point like this in it : "*This wave equation is equivalent to Turing Reaction-diffusion equations*". How can that be proved?

[image]